# Is there an algorithm to transform arguments from text to "standard form"?

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language, artificial-intelligence

Consider the following deductive [argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deductive_reasoning), in the form of a paragraph:

> Drugs use should be legalised, because it is an attack against individual freedom, which is a founding element of our societies. At the moment, the state is prohibiting that freedom to people.

This argument can be [reconstructed](https://sites.google.com/site/mccormickphilosophy/home/critical-thinking-syllabus/critical-thinking-schedule/reconstructing-arguments) into the "standard form" (where P stands for premise, and C for conclusion):

> P1 Freedom is a founding element of our societies
>
> P2 The prohibition of drugs use by the state is an attack on freedom
>
> $------$
>
> C Drugs use should be legalised.

Is there an algorithm/method/tool in AI, Natural Language Processing, or machine learning that is able to translate an argument in the form of a text into the "standard form"? Or perhaps easier, an algorithm that can transform an argument in its standard form into a paragraph? (They are probably related)

Comment: You assume that people in real-life make such structured, logical arguments? Or do you have transcripts of discussions by logicians? Otherwise I doubt such algorithm would return any meaningful output...

Comment: no i don't think so.